# How to uninstall GNU parallel?

Tags: gnu-parallel

I installed `GNU parallel` with `(wget pi.dk/3 -qO - ||  curl pi.dk/3/) | sh`, but I believe it is preferable to install it with `Homebrew` instead, because that makes updating easier.

How do I remove everything the script created? I'm using OS X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(wget pi.dk/3 -qO - ||  curl pi.dk/3/) | bash
cd parallel-20*/
make uninstall
```