# How To Install Or Switch To Older Version of GNU Parallel?

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin, gnu, gnu-parallel

I'm working with a related issue to GNU Parallel where we suspect a bug in the most recent GNU parallel release ([How To Avoid SIGCHLD error In Bash Script That Uses GNU Parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39754323/how-to-avoid-sigchld-error-in-bash-script-that-uses-gnu-parallel)) and I would like to revert to an older version.

Originally, this is the code I used to install:

```
wd=$(mktemp -d)
wget -nc -P $wd ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/parallel/parallel-latest.tar.bz2

cd $wd
tar -xf parallel-latest.tar.bz2
cd parallel-*
./configure && make && make install
```

(Code found here: [which cygwin package to get `parallel` command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37212894/which-cygwin-package-to-get-parallel-command))

This is the code I found to uninstall:

```
(wget pi.dk/3 -qO - ||  curl pi.dk/3/) | bash
cd parallel-20*/
make uninstall
```

(Code found here: [How to uninstall GNU parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344272/how-to-uninstall-gnu-parallel))

Would it be correct to uninstall and then install the older package? Or, is there a way to install the older package and specify which version I would like to use?

Your insight and support of this question is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From README (replace 20160922 with the version you want):

```
wget http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/parallel/parallel-20160922.tar.bz2
bzip2 -dc parallel-20160922.tar.bz2 | tar xvf -
cd parallel-20160922
./configure && make && sudo make install
```